# Run scheduled task with different user that the one that it was created

Tags: c#, windows, scheduled-tasks

I need to create a task for task scheduler from c# code using a user and a password for creating it.

Then the program that is scheduled, I want to be runned using a different account then the user that was used for creating the task.

Is it possible ? If yes, how?

Comment: The answer will depend on what version of Windows you're running, please update your question to include that.

Comment: You should use this library: http://taskscheduler.codeplex.com/

Answer (score 1):

After you create a Scheduled Task in Windows, open the task properties. There should be a Run As textbox on the Task tab, that allows you to type in a different user's name. Then you can create a password.